# Is WiFi data usage included in the "Data Usage" screen?

Tags: wi-fi, data-monitoring

Android devices feature a Data usage screen, accessible from the main pull-down menu.

The data usage page lists both the total data consumed and the data consumed per application.

[image: Data usage screenshot]

**Is WiFi data included in this count, or only Cellular data?**

P.S. It makes sense that the metered data count only includes Cellular data, but I would like to have a canonical source to settle this issue.

Comment: Based on your screenshot it only measures Cellular data. Can you please check if the menu / 3-Point overflow button includes the option to show wifi data aswell? It does on my device - but I'm running Cyanogenmod so I'm not sure if this option is included in a Stock-Rom aswell :)

Comment: No, There's no such option - I can't add or remove WiFi from the summary.

Comment: What is your device model and Android OS? On Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, the WiFi usage can be enabled by going into the overflow menu (3 dots), and select "Show WiFi" (AFAIK, it's added since Marshmallow though). But by default, it only shows cellular data.

Comment: Did you check this resource: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819524?hl=en?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are seeing here is cellular data (mobile data) only.

I am not sure what you would count as a "canonical answer", but the following three screen captures have been taken from a stock android ROM with Android 5.1.1 (as you can see by the presence of the Samsung bloatware):

[image: data usage with mobile data only] [image: kebab menu for data usage] [image: Wi-Fi data usage]
<sup>Data Usage (default) / with hamburger-menu / data usage, WiFi tab (click images for larger variants)</sup>

The first screen capture is the same as yours.

The second screen capture shows the menu that pops up if you touch the kebab icon (the three vertical dots.)  As you see, the menu contains a "Show Wi-Fi usage" option.  If you enable showing Wi-Fi usage, two tabs are added to the screen, one for mobile data (probably "cellular data" in your case) and another for Wi-Fi.

The third screen capture shows how the "Wi-Fi" tab looks like on the screen.